# Creating a universal boolean in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, boolean

I write:

`bool example = true` under the code for say, a button event: `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

I am trying to change the value of this bool when the user pushes a button.

The problem is, my bool is only recognized in this context. When I try to use it under `private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` Visual Studio notifies me of an error saying the name doesn't exist in the context.

Where should I be putting the code for a bool?

Thanks.

Comment: you should definitely learn more about the basics of the programming and the language, because a scope of variables is really a fundamental knowledge you shouldn't be programming any UI without...

Comment: Definitely! I'm actually watching a series by The New Boston covering if statements. I just got a tad sidetracked and thought this would be interesting to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move it to class-level: that is, a member of the `Form` class:

```
public class YourForm : Form {
    private bool _example = true;

    // ... your event handlers here

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        _example = false; // etc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Where should I be putting the code for a bool?

**Outside** of your methods, in the `class level`

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
   // here is class level

   public void SomeMethod()
   {
      // here is method level
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a member of the class;

```
public class MyClass
{
    private bool example = false;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        example = true;
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //example available
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use static variable or class level.

Comment: It would be great if you could add a code example or more details!